# capture String and store it in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

I'm trying to capture a text-generated string (client / session based) for when a user is uploading an image.

Output when doing `db.collection.find();` from console when uploading:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("590c67f472667e031fe80a9d"),
"path" : "uploads/bicycle.jpg",
"originalname" : "bicycle.jpg",
"__v" : 0
```

Here I want to have `"imagelocation" : "N/A"` also.

The string is based on a users location when uploading the image.
I want to connect that specific strings value to the image-objects ID as displayed above.

App.js:

```
/image UPLOAD TO MONGODB

 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var path = require('path');
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 //To get the access for the functions defined in imagefile.js class
 var routes = require('./imagefile');

 // connect to mongo,
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/gps');

 app.use('/', routes);

 // To get all the images/files stored in MongoDB
 app.get('/images', function(req, res) {
   routes.getImages(function(err, genres) {
      if (err) {
         throw err;
      }
 res.json(genres);

 });
 });

 app.get('/images/:id', function(req, res) {
    routes.getImageById(req.params.id, function(err, genres) {
    if (err) {
       throw err;
    }

 res.send(genres.path)
 });
 });
```

path and originalname are declared as follows in my imagefile.js:

```
var imageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 path: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
 },
 originalname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
 },
 imagelocation:{ // format for storing
   type: String,
   required: true
 }

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', stringClass);
var Image = module.exports = mongoose.model('files', stringClass);

router.getImages = function(callback, limit) {

 Image.find(callback).limit(limit);
}


router.getImageById = function(id, callback) {

 Image.findById(id, callback);

}

router.addImage = function(image, callback) {
 Image.create(image, callback);
}
//multer
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function(req, file, cb) {
 cb(null, 'uploads/')
 },
 filename: function(req, file, cb) {
 cb(null, file.originalname);
 },
 imagelocation: function(req,file,cb){
   cb(null, $('#coordinates').innerHTML);
 }
});

var upload = multer({
 storage: storage
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('layouts/main.handlebars');
});

router.post('/', upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {

 res.send(req.files);

 var path = req.files[0].path;
 var imageName = req.files[0].originalname;
 var imagepath = {};
 imagepath['path'] = path;
 imagepath['originalname'] = imageName;


 router.addImage(imagepath, function(err) {

 });

});

module.exports = router;
```

HTML:

```
<p id="coordinates">String is generated here</p>
```

TL;DR - how would i capture a string and send that along with the image when uploading it to my MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

To send a string a long with your image file, you just send it along with your form on submission. For instance in a hidden input field.

Then, on submission, you can access it as part of the `req.body` object

Here's an example (from an API, but you get the idea):

```
app.post('/api/file', function(req, res){
    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage
    }).single('imageFile')
    upload(req, res, function(err){
        if(err){
            // handle any errors here ...
        }
        console.log(req.body)// <-- here you can access your text string as 'req.body.yourStringIdentifier'
        res.json({success: true, msg: 'File uploaded'});
    })
})
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask :)

---

Edit: Full example

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
})

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback){
        callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback){
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
})

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage
    }).single('imageFile')
    upload(req, res, function(err){
        console.log(req.body.textInput);
        res.end('File is uploaded');
    })
})

var port = process.env.PORT || 7850
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
})
```

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>INDEX</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="file" name="imageFile">
            <input type="text" name="textInput">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code works when I run it from the terminal with `nodemon server.js`. When the form is submitted, the contents of the text field is printed to the console.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that was the idea at first, however "undefined" is returned whenever we try to log the response. Could you try to implement what you've written in a more comprehensive answer? Thanks!

Comment: I've tried now for an hour to make your solution work, but i simply cannot. :/ I can't see how this would store the string in the same db-object for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Joel,
     As per the Multer documentation, the Disk Storage 
`var storage = multer.diskStorage({.....})`
engine gives you full control on storing files to disk and it has only two options available, destination and filename. They are both functions that determine where the file should be stored.

- Destination is used to determine within which folder the uploaded files should be stored
- Filename is used to determine what the file should be named inside the folder.

Hence your way of defining the multer.diskStorage is wrong.

If you are trying to upload it into MongoDB refer the following link: 
https://ciphertrick.com/2017/02/28/file-upload-with-nodejs-and-gridfs-mongodb/

If you want to store the file in disk storage and then upload some information about the file that is stored using your schema

```
var imageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   path: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          trim: true
         },
   originalname: {
          type: String,
          required: true
      },
   imagelocation:{ // format for storing
          type: String,
          required: true
      }

      });
```

Then make changes in

```
 var imagepath = {};
 imagepath['path'] = path;
 imagepath['originalname'] = imageName;
  /* provide logic here as mentioned by  David Stenstrøm to read it 
     from request.body and move it to the image schema object */

 router.addImage(imagepath, function(err) {

 });
```

Hope I clarified your query :) :)

Comment: Is this the answer for your query?